Помогите найти ошибку в коде Задача ЕГЭ информатика
Задача звучит так:
Сколько существует чисел, восьмеричная запись которых состоит из пяти цифр, не начинается с нечётных цифр, не оканчивается цифрами 2 и 6 и содержит не более двух цифр 7?
Ответ: 9135
Но у меня ответ 12288, не могу понять почему так, вроде все правильно
Вот мой код :
from itertools import *

alphabet = '01234567'
cnt = 0
for i in product(alphabet, repeat=5):
    if int(i[0]) % 2 == 0:
        if i[-1] != '2' and i[-1] != '6':
            if i.count('7') <= 7:
                cnt += 1

print(cnt)


Нет, ошибка не потому что при первом условии допускается 0 в начале, проверил, если исключить 0 из цифр, которые могут быть в начале, все равно ответ не сходится

if int(i[0]) % 2 == 0 and int(i[0]) > 0:
    if i[-1] != '2' and i[-1] != '6':
        if i.count('7') <= 2:
            cnt += 1


from itertools import product

alphabet = '01234567'
cnt = 0
for i in product(alphabet, repeat=5):
    if i[0] in '2468':
        if i[-1] not in '26':
            if i.count('7') <= 2:
                cnt += 1

print(cnt)

